# How to save inversed DCT image

Tags: matlab

Here is the code:

```
imshow(idct2(CDCT),[0 255])
i=idct2(CDCT),[0 255];
   imwrite(i,'fa.tif');
```

When I display the image, it works fine. But only white image with few black lines is saved (incorrect image). Please tell what I am doing wrong. :)

Comment: I don't know what exactly your data, but you can save it directly from the figure, with `save`, or `export`.

Comment: But the image has to be scaled...

Comment: CDCT in the dct of an image

Comment: It will be saved as you see it in the figure window.

Comment: I have saved the image using i=idct2(CDCT);
   save('fa.tif','i');
 but when I open the image it says that its corrupted

Comment: Type only `imshow(idct2(CDCT),[0 255])`. Then select the "save" icon on the figure window (usually third from left), or select File->Save as..., or File->Export Setup, or Edit->Copy Figure

Comment: Is there not any other way to save it using code?

Comment: Sure there are ways, but it difficult to say while I don't have your data- class, dimensions, values range, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image data that you are writing to a file using `imwrite` is of type `double` or `single` (which yours is), then all values are expected to be between 0 and 1. Your values are mostly greater than 1 since your data is all between 0 and 255, so this is why the image is appearing as mostly white. You can easily normalize your data using `mat2gray` prior to calling `imwrite`.

```
imwrite(mat2gray(i), 'fa.tif');
```

Otherwise, if you pass `uint8` values to `imwrite`, the values are expected to be within the range of 0 to 255 (as your data is). So you can simply cast your input data as a `uint8` prior to saving

```
imwrite(uint8(i), 'fa.tif');
```

Comment: It is working fine but there is a slight difference in some pixels. How can I improve that?

Comment: @user3102085 You can't unfortunately. Your original data is `double` (64-bits) and your resulting tif is 8-bits so the data is not going to be exactly equal once you load it back in. The best you could get would be to try to save a 64-bit tiff but even that won't be exactly the same. If you need it to be the same, consider saving your data within a .mat file instead